# Page redirect from modal popup

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, coldfusion, bootstrap-modal

I have a simple modal dialog box like below on a page, on click of Go button, the user should navigate to another page, based on selected option in the dropdown; which looks like `mysite.com/<cfoutput>#product_name#</cfoutput>`; I get an error and it is taking me nowhere. I tried couple different things, must be missing something real small. Any insights? thanks

```
<div id="home-choose-spec" class="modal fade home-spec-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">            
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm login-modal">
            <div class="modal-content white-bg rounded">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button">x</button>
                    <div class="reg-block border-none">
                        <div class="reg-block-header">
                            <h2 class="dark-blue bold">Select a product:</h2>                                                                   
                        </div>

                        <div class="margin-bottom-20">

                            <form class="reg-page" method="post">
                                <select name="pid" id="pid" class="form-control input margin-bottom-20">
                                <cfoutput query="products"> 
                             <option value="#pid#">#product_name#</option>
                     </cfoutput>
                                </select>                                                             
                             <a class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-home-spec-choice light-blue-bg white bold rounded" href=’mysite.com/<cfoutput>#product_name#</cfoutput>’>Go!</a>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What does your error look like?

Comment: Oh I figured, the product_name is undefined. How can I get the selected option name, and properly redirect based on the selected name? thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what the problem is... whether you're getting a javascript error or cf error but it seems like you're trying to use a product name within the same instance of the same page as the population.

This is entirely possible, but not how you're doing it. It looks like you're trying to get the value of the box as it changes without submitting the page.

Add an id to the link, I chose `mlink`.

You can, on initial load, use cf to populate the value equal to the default selected option's value

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button">x</button>
    <div class="reg-block border-none">
        <div class="reg-block-header">
            <h2 class="dark-blue bold">Select a product:</h2>                                                                   
        </div>

        <div class="margin-bottom-20">

            <form class="reg-page" method="post">
                <select name="pid" id="pid" class="form-control input margin-bottom-20">
                <cfoutput query="products"> 
             <option value="#pid#">#product_name#</option>
     </cfoutput>
                </select>                                                             
             <a id="mlink" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-home-spec-choice light-blue-bg white bold rounded" href=’#’>Go!</a>
            </form>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

And then use javascript like this

```
document.getElementById('mlink').onclick = function (e) {
    var pidselect = document.getElementById('pid')
    this.href = "http://somesite.com/"+ pidselect.options[pidselect.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gr2oju3L/1/) Demo with two more lines of the code in the function to catch the link before it fires, alert you with the href value, and stop the firing (so that you don't leave the jsfiddle page.

Note that the html in the jsfiddle is different than it is here (I removed cfoutputs and duplicated an option so there was something to demonstrate that it is working, so if you copy html, copy it from this page.